# React react-localize-redux translation inside HTMLelement-properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have implemented the react-localize-redux for language-translations in an application i am working with. I do get the translations inside html-elements, but i am failing to get translations to work with html-element-properties. For example input value.

It works using  like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label className="atom_required" htmlFor="name">
        <Translate id="textexample" />:
    </label>
</form>
```

But if i try this id returns object Object:

```
<div className="atom_bottomButtons">
    <input
        id="atom_bottomButtons__submit"
        disabled
        className="btn btn-primary"
        type="submit"
        value={<Translate id="textexample" />}
        />
</div>
```

Does someone know how to map properties of html-elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [the render-prop API](https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/#html-translations):

```
<div className="atom_bottomButtons">
<Translate>{
   ({ translate }) => {
      return <input
        id="atom_bottomButtons__submit"
        disabled
        className="btn btn-primary"
        type="submit"
        value={translate("textexample")}
        />
  }
}</Translate>
</div>
```

See also: [`translate`'s API](https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/#translate)